# How can I map two component properties of the same type separately in NHibernate ByCode?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have a need to reuse a component type in multiple classes, but the mapping of that component type will vary depending on which root class it's in. We are using the ByCode mapping API to achieve this.

It looks like it should be simple: just explicitly map the component differently for each class.

But the following test fails under NHibernate 4.0.4.4000:

```
[TestFixture]
public class DuplicateComponentMappingTests
{
    [Test]
    public void TopLevelComponentsAreSpecialisedForRootEntity()
    {
        var cfg = ConfigureWithMappings(m => {
            m.Class<RootA>(r => {
                r.Id(x => x.Id);
                r.Component(x => x.Component, c => {
                    c.Property(x => x.PropertyA);
                });
            });
            m.Class<RootB>(r => {
                r.Id(x => x.Id);
                r.Component(x => x.Component, c => {
                    c.Property(x => x.PropertyB);
                });
            });
        });
        using (var sessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory())
        {
            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                session.CreateSQLQuery("create table RootA ( Id int, PropertyA int )").ExecuteUpdate();
                session.CreateSQLQuery("create table RootB ( Id int, PropertyB int )").ExecuteUpdate();
            }

            using (var session = sessionFactory.OpenSession())
            {
                session.Save(new RootA { Component = new Component { PropertyA = 1 } }); // Fails because there's no PropertyB column, even though we didn't map it for RootA.
                session.Flush();
            }
        }
    }

    private Configuration ConfigureWithMappings(Action<ModelMapper> map)
    {
        ...
    }
}

class RootA
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
}
class RootB
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Component Component { get; set; }
}
class Component
{
    public virtual int PropertyA { get; set; }
    public virtual int PropertyB { get; set; }
}
```

To make matters worse, our actual component class contains components itself, to about 4 levels deep, which also need to vary their mappings by root entity.

Things I've tried:

- Using different names for the component property on each entity. No luck; looks like the mappings are shared based on the component's type.
- Using separate ModelMappers for each root entity. Not an option, since in each case the component's mappings may depend upon another class mapping and I get 'duplicate' errors if I add that class to both ModelMappers.

Answer (score 1):

Tracked this down to a pair of known bugs, around since 3.2/3.3:

- https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3491
- https://nhibernate.jira.com/browse/NH-3114

So the solution for now appears to be 'don't do that then'. I'll try to submit a fix once I fully understand the problem.